# identify rows returned by the first "select" and rows returned by the second (in "union" query) inserting an additional field

Tags: mysql, union

I have a query like:

```
(SELECT F1, F2, F3 .....)
UNION
(SELECT F1, F2, F3 .....)
```

The result is like

```
F1   F2   F3
A    B    C
D    E    F
G    H    I
```

I need to distinguish the rows returned by the first "select" from the ones returned by the second.
I would like to do this by adding a field containing the number of the "select". Something like this:

```
Sel  F1   F2   F3
1    A    B    C
1    D    E    F
2    G    H    I
```

The number will also be used for other operations.
Is there a way to do what I desire?
Thanks in advance to anyone who'll give suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(SELECT 1 Sel, F1, F2, F3 .....)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 2 Sel, F1, F2, F3 .....)
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the dumb question, I'find the way by myself:

```
(SELECT F1, F2, F3, '1' AS Sel .....)
UNION
(SELECT F1, F2, F3, '2' AS Sel .....)
```